# Wavefunction evolution in a Double-Slit setup after detection

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, time-evolution, propagator

If a detector is placed at one of the slits in a double-slit setup, the probability density reduces to a bright fringe opposite the detector which went off. I want to understand why this happens from the viewpoint of Schrodinger evolution.

Take the $z$ axis to point along the line joining the slits and $x$ pointing from the slits toward the screen.

When you measure which slit the electron goes through, the electron collapses to an eigenstate whose $z$ value is determined (that is, within some uncertainty (which can be made arbitrarily small)) but whose momentum $p_x$ is insignificantly affected by the measurement. The state of the electron once it has been detected at slit $A$ (arbitrarily small width), is then
\begin{equation*}
    \psi_0\left(z\right) \propto \delta\left(z-z_0\right)
\end{equation*}
where we are not interested in the $x,y$ dependence. I just want to know how the $z$ dependence evolves to give rise to the bright fringe. Then
\begin{equation*}
    \psi\left(\mathbf{r},t\right) = \int d^3r' K\left(\mathbf{r},t;\mathbf{r}'\right)\psi_0\left(\mathbf{r}'\right)
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    K\left(\mathbf{r},t;\mathbf{r}'\right) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar t}}e^{i\frac{m}{2\hbar}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right)^2/t}
\end{equation*}
So, again, just considering the $z$ dependent portion of $\psi\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)$,
\begin{equation*}
    \psi\left(\mathbf{r},t\right) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int dz' e^{i\left(\left(z-z'\right)^2/t-\pi/4\right)}\delta\left(z'-z_0\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{i\left(\left(z-z_0\right)^2/t-\pi/4\right)}
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \vert\psi\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)\vert^2 \propto 1/t
\end{equation*}
Why does this give a result independent of $z$? Shouldn't I get something like a Gaussian centered at $z_0$ which spreads out in time? What part of the above needs to be amended?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues within what you wrote that should be addressed, I'll just speak my piece here.

**As for what to do:**

Rather than letting the w.f. collapse at the slit, consider the joint w.f. of the particle with a 1-qubit detector. I think Sean Carroll did it nicely here: https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2019/09/21/the-notorious-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser/ . The decoherence of the particle by interaction with another degree of freedom is what makes the previously-summed terms no longer sum / interfere with each other.

**As for what you did that was not correct:**

Notice that the delta-function-after-measurement thing is incorrect here (as very often becomes clear when trying to apply it to a real example) because unless the measurement is too destructive, the particle continues with a similar momentum as it already had (it proceeds towards the screen). A delta function is symmetric and does not have a bias in momentum in any particular direction. All delta-function collapse in general is wishful thinking in the sense that it gives incorrect results but we keep it around because it's simple and we don't have a clean alternative within the textbook formalism. I believe textbooks have a responsibility to clearly point this out when the formalism is introduced, but that's just life, the books aren't perfect.

Lastly, the notion that $|\psi(\vec{r},t)|^2$ gives the distribution for the double slit is also wrong even in principle which can be made clear in a number of ways:

- The desired result is a distribution in the $y,z$ coordinates, since it is a distribution across a 2d screen (I allowed $x$ to be normal to the screen here). So we have an extra $x$ and $t$ here. What to do with those?
- The units are wrong. We need units of $1/length^2$ so that when integrated $dx dy$ across a detector area it gives a probability.

In fact predicting results for double-slit-like experiments in general doesn't fit well into the textbook QM framework. So you've hit on a lot of weak points of the theory in your question. For single particles hitting a screen you can use the scattering formalism. For the general case of multiple interacting particles hitting the screen you'd have to check out the literature on arrival times in quantum mechanics.